# Outputing index of negative numbers in a list (using structural recursion)

Tags: python, recursion

If given a list:

```
a = [-1,2,3,4,-5]
```

How can I approach the problem of outputing a list of index's that is negative?

```
a.function = [0,4]
```

EDIT: my bad typo.

Comment: There is no index `5` because your list has only 5 elements.

Comment: The referenced question would answer your question, i.e. how to do it using recursion.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = [-1,2,3,4,-5]
print [idx for idx, item in enumerate(my_list) if item < 0]
# [0, 4]
```

You can do this with recursion, like this

```
my_list = [-1,2,3,4,-5]
def rec(current_list, idx, result):
    if len(current_list) == idx:
        return result
    if current_list[idx] < 0:
        result.append(idx)
    return rec(current_list, idx + 1, result)

print rec(my_list, 0, [])
# [0, 4]
```

Comment: Removed my erroneous comment, @thefourtheye.

Comment: Curious, is there anyway to do it?

Comment: @user3225528 Could you please explain?

Comment: The title says it all.  Using `recursion`.